# Django MissingFileError: Path is a directory

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to deploy my project static files on S3 AWS but when i collectstatic on my terminal, i got this error. I heard that it looks like you i'm trying to include a static asset in my template, but i have specified a directory instead of a file... and i do not understand this :/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 57, in __call__
static_file = self.find_file(environ['PATH_INFO'])
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 75, in find_file
return self.get_static_file(path, url)
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 111, in get_static_file
self.add_stat_headers(headers, path, url)
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 121, in add_stat_headers
file_stat = stat_regular_file(path)
File "/home/damian/proj1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/utils.py", line 30, in stat_regular_file
raise MissingFileError('Path is a directory: {0}'.format(path))
MissingFileError: Path is a directory: /home/damian/proj1/blog/static_in_pro/our_static
[08/Aug/2016 13:14:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

my (not all) settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_env", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
#'/var/www/static/',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_env", "media_root")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

MEDIAFILES_DIRS = (MEDIA_ROOT)


#AWS S3 STATICK FILES

AWS_HEADERS = {  # see     http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
}

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '###'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '###'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '###'


AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

Thanks for help and to indicate the correct path for the ongoing work!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That error is from WhiteNoise, but you don't need to use WhiteNoise if you're serving your static files from S3. You should remove the WhiteNoise references from your `wsgi.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only `django-storages` you'll need to specify

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

instead `STATICFILES_STORAGE`